# Cannot find document with query string parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to find a document in my db by using a query string that refers to a `user_id` defined on a `profile` schema like so:

```
ProfileSchema = Schema(
  user_id: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  vehicules: [VehiculeSchema]
  home: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'home'}
  travel: [TravelSchema]
  diet: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'diet'}
  actions: [ActionSchema]
)
```

When I run `db.profiles.find({user_id: "55e3393e95cafd4c23a00756"})` in the mongo shell, I find my document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e3393e95cafd4c23a00757"), "user_id" : "55e3393e95cafd4c23a00756", "actions" : [ ], "diet" : [ { "portion_period" : "year", "portions" : 1, "footprint" : 100, "type" : "fish" } ], "travel" : [ ], "energy" : [ { "bill" : "100", "period" : "month", "type" : "electricity" }, { "period" : "week", "type" : "electricity" }, { "period" : "month", "type" : "gas" } ], "vehicules" : [ ], "commute" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

However when performing the same query in my code using the `mongoose` orm, It does not find the document. **Syntax is coffeescript**

```
Profile.find {user_id: ObjectId(req.query.user_id)}, (err, profile)->
  console.log 'FINDING PROFILE', arguments
    if !err
      if profile
        res.json profiles:[profile]
      else
        res.sendStatus 404
```

I also tried without casting the result to a ObjectId, without more success.
I also tried to use `findOne` instead of `find`, but it returns null instead of an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e3393e95cafd4c23a00757"), "user_id" : "55e3393e95cafd4c23a00756"...
```

This document has the `userId` stored as a hexadecimal `String` representation of the `ObjectId`, not an `ObjectId` itself. Queries in MongoDB are type-sensitive, so a `String("55e3393e95cafd4c23a00756")` and `ObjectId("55e3393e95cafd4c23a00756")` are serialized differently. When a MongoDB client encounters an `ObjectId` instance, it serializes it into the `BSON` `ObjectId` type.

```
Profile.find {user_id: req.query.user_id}, (err, profile)-> ...
```

will work for this particular document, albeit storing them as proper `ObjectId`s would be a better choice.

Comment: This did it. When I was creating my model, I was indeed adding the `user_id` as a string. I added a cast to `ObjectId` and it works fine!